# How can I recover deleted info from a Word document after saving and reopening?

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted all of my document that I was writting in Word. I closed it and hit save changes mistakenly. Now that I've reopened it I can't seem to get Ctrl-Z (undo) to recover my info.

Is there another way to get my document contents back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Windows Vista or 7, view the file properties (Alt+Enter) and there is a "Previous versions" tab. But that also depends if you run regular backups and create restore points.

Tip: get used to keyboard shortcuts, it really helps minimize clicking save by accident. We all learn the hard way eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what I do to some documents before deleting as I don't want them to be recovered or undeleted. So my condolences to you...

Answer (score 1):

In the future you may have luck turning "Track Changes" on, but that won't save this document.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 if you right click on the document there is an option to restore previous versions, for example one that might have been created at a Restore point.